# onclick handler in jquery is getting called first time, but subsequent time not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have written the following javascript to handle click event on checkbox. It is working when first time the page is loading but subsequent time the function that I have written to handle on click event, not getting called. I am pasting code here:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            function getCookie(name) {
                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
                return cookieValue;
            }
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();

           $('#election_done').click(function() {
                if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $.ajax({
                       url: '/voting/update_election_status/',
                       type: 'POST',
                        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
                        },
                       success: function(data) {
                            $('#count_vote').html(data);
                       }
                    });
                }else{
                    $('#count_vote').remove();
                }
           });
        });
```

In the above code, **$(this).is(":checked")** is coming false always except first time. Can please anyone suggest what mistake I am doing in the above code.

Comment: First suggestion is to use `change` instead of `click` for checkboxes.

Comment: Does the `#election_done` element exists inside the `#count_vote` element? Then that's what's causing your problem.

Comment: @Sushanth--it is not working.

Comment: @lagerone, #election_done element does not exist in #count_vote element

Comment: Are you sure the handler is not being called? If you put `alert('triggered');` before the `if($(this).is(":checked")) {` line does it alert each time you click the `#election_done` element?

Comment: Yes this alert is being called. But $(this).is(":checked") is coming false always.

Comment: There must be something else that is changing the state of `#election_done`. Maybe another `click` or `change` handler. I would recommend simplifying your code as much as you can to track down the issue. (e.g. remove ajax call while debugging)

Comment: can you paste your html?